# How To Convert The Grand Total of a Pivot Table as a Value for Each Row in a New Column

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, measure

**Overall goal for my report:**

I am creating a pivot table in excel right now (eventually in Power Bi) that will update daily through data imports to reflect weekly changes in sales. I am then trying to perform a Z score analysis on each week to see if there are any outliers within the data.

What I will need to do is be able to subtract a mean of all of the data from each weekly set of sales, then divide it by the standard deviation.

**Current thought process for data:**

If I can get the grand total at the bottom, could I get that as a value entered for each row in another column? Can I do it as a total average and a total standard deviation? I can do it outside of a pivot table, but I want something in a pivot table so it auto-populates.

[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qCGH.png)

[Desired Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA9vc.png)

Comment: Why not try implementing your ideas and seeing how you get on?

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this in at least two approaches:

1. Dynamic calculation using measures
2. Back-end calculation

The first approach consists of defining measures in the following context:

```
CALCULATE([MEASURES], All('Calendar'), VALUES('Calendar'[Year]), VALUES('Calendar'[Month]))
```

This allows you to calculate a measure in a context that consider the entire month. Therefore, for each day you would have a measure that gives you the stdev of the entire month.

**Pro**: dynamic; fast to implement; can be based on measures already defined
**Cons**: more calculation in front-end slows down your report

The second approach consists of pre-calculating this values in the back-end. Here you have two possible approaches:

1. Data source: add these new columns in the data source (e.g. Database)

**Pro**: best-practices and clean approach
**Cons**: static; cannot use measures already defined

2. Calculated Column in DAX: define the value as a Calculated Column in the back-end of Power BI using the same structured defined for the Measure:

   `CALCULATE([MEASURES], All('Calendar'), VALUES('Calendar'[Year]), VALUES('Calendar'[Month]))`

**Pro**: fast to implement
**Cons**: static; really against best-practices

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI I used following measures (replace 'stack' with 'your table name')

```
Total StdDev = CALCULATE(STDEV.P(stack[sum of sales]), ALL(stack))

TotalMean = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(stack[sum of sales]),ALL(stack))

Z score = (SUM(stack[sum of sales]) - [TotalMean])/[Total StdDev]
```

I used average to calculate MEAN and I get different result to yours (please see below).
If you can share formula that you used to calculate 'TotalMean' maybe I can update it.

[image]